# How can I make a Minecraft Server private?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to understand how servers work and if it was possible for me to make the Minecraft server private so only myself and a select few of my friends could play?

Answer (score 7):

Once you have run the server software and port forwarded, in a file named server properties, set whitelist to true. When you've done that, there will be another file called whitelist where you can list the players names that are allowed to join.

Comment: Where is the file?

Comment: thw whitelist file and the properties file can be found in the same folder as your minecraft-server.jar file! or maybe if you are using plugins it may be in another folder!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the whitelisting option mentioned, you can simply turn on your server when only you and your friends are playing and turn it off when you're done (this will save your progress and no one else will be able to log in without you knowing).  Just leave the server address as the default external IP.  It's extremely unlikely that anyone will find it and log in.  I host my own mini server all the time and only people we know have ever logged in.

Answer (score 1):

To create your server for free, follow these steps:

If you want to know How To [play Minecraft with friends on pc](https://techinfogeek.com/play-minecraft-with-friends-on-pc/) for free then follow :

1. Make sure you have installed Java on your PC. If not, then go to this [link](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp).
2. Download the correct version of Java as it is necessary to create your Minecraft server. Download the 64-bit version for the 64 bit and 32-bit version for the 32-bit computer.
3. Next, you want to download is the Minecraft Server Software from [here](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/).
4. Create a New Folder on Desktop for the Minecraft Server (you can name it whatever you want)
5. Copy and Paste the downloaded server.jar file on this folder.
6. If you are not able to see the extension like I do in the above photo, then click on View>Options.

And than Uncheck the “Hide extensions for known file types.”

7. Then you will be able to see the .jar extension.
8. Next, you need to make a new text document and open it with notepad.
9. Paste this code in that file:

   `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.15.2.jar nogui`
10. Next, you need to edit the “minecraft_server.1.15.2.jar” with “server.jar” as shown:
11. Press Enter and type “PAUSE” because we want to pause the script when it runs, and then we will be able to see if there is an error with the script or not.
12. Then Save the file as start.bat.

Make sure you select “All Files” as shown(you can give the file whatever name you want but make sure that you insert .bat extension at the end)

13. Delete the .txt file.
14. Double click on the start.bat file and let it run. (this will start your server)
15. Now you will see that it failed to load. So now you have to open the eula.txt file.
16. Edit the “eula=false” to “eula=true” and save it.
17. Rerun the .bat file. And you will see that the server has loaded this time.
18. When you see Done, then type “stop” and hit enter to stop the server. (because you do not want to exit out of your server as exiting out will not save your progress in the Minecraft game)
19. Now right-click on ‘server.properties‘ and open it with notepad. You can now see your server settings.
20. Now open the start.bat file again to run your server and let it load.
21. Open Minecraft, click on Multiplayer and then click on Add Server.
22. And now, you have to add the Server Name and Server Address.

You can add any Server Name you want, but in the Server Address field, you have to type – ‘localhost.’

And then click on Done, you will see that the server is online and you can join it.

23. For the next step, you have to go to this link.
24. Now, this step is kind of different for everybody as everyone is going to have a different router. In this step, you have to port forward your router.

Here you will have to find your router. (For example – If your router is TP-Link than go to the letter T and search for TP-Link and click it)

25. For this step, you have to physically go up to your router and see for yourself to know the Model number.

Look for the same Model number on this website. ( For Example – If your TP-Link Model number is Archer C20 than you click on that)

26. This page is going to give you the rundown on how to port forward your router. And you will get your Username and Password on this page as well as the IP Address.
27. Now open a New Tab in Google Chrome and write your IP Address, as shown below:
28. Enter your Username & Password, as shown in step 26.
29. Then you will get to this page.
30. Then go to Forwarding>Virtual Servers and click on Add New. You will get to this page.
31. Enter the following information in the respective fields:

> Service Port: 25565
>
> Internal Port: 25565
>
> IP Address:
>
> Protocol: All
>
> Status: Enabled
>
> Common Service Port: –

Then Press Save and your Port Forwarding are created.

32. Go to Google and type in “what is my IP address.” And you will get your IP.
33. Now share this IP Address with your friends who want to join your server, and they will be able to connect it via this IP Address.
34. Go to Minecraft> Multiplayer> Add Server & add this IP Address in the Server Address field and click Done.

So this is how you create your own Minecraft Server for free without any payment or monthly fees. Now you can make your own Minecraft Servers yourself.

Go here if you have any problems: [How to Play Minecraft with friends on PC](https://techinfogeek.com/play-minecraft-with-friends-on-pc/)

Answer (score 0):

In game or in the console you can do `/whitelist on` which will only allow certain players to join. To add a player to the list do `/whitelist add {player name}`. To remove: `/whitelist remove {player name}`. To see the list of people on the whitelist, do `/whitelist` and it will give you more information! **If you are using a console (above) do not use the "/" in front of the command!**